# Add views to UIScrollView only when will be visible

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview

I am creating views at run time using heavy data, and adding these views to a UIScrollView.

The problem here is,it takes a lote of time to create the screen, which is not so good user experience. 
I want to create initialy only for the part of screen that are visible, and add/create the others views when scrolling the UIScrollView.

Any tips about the best approuch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put the whole thing in a uitableview  with cells of varying heights instead of scrollview. that way its easier to keep track of the visible cells.

Comment: i can't, because since the views can have complex layouts, i can't afford to reuse cells. My first approach was to create a collection view, but with the complex layouts i got problems every time a cell is reused

Comment: You are not forced to reuse the cells, it only happens if you use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method. If you instead just instantiate new cells on demand and save them in a separate list (or cache), then you can fetch cells from this cache when the user scrolls backwards so you avoid the reuse problem.

Comment: can i make the same for a collectionView?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITableView`, set cell separator to none and use variable height of row cell. Do as you always do with `UITableViewCell` i.e. deque cell using identifier.

This is the best approach to deal with the memory issue and for large amount of data.

Also you can do the same for `UICollectionViewCell` too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i cant implement your solution. I already have a collectionView implemented but since i have a big number of possible type of cells (30) i am facing "performance" issues when the collectionView reload each cell (the views have complex layouts).